# direction of a VQFN pinout IC

Tags: layout

I want to use the 
[TCA9548A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9548a.pdf)  in QFN format, I have diffuclties understanding the direction of pins, is it here really in clockwise  ? as shown in page 33 of the datasheet ?

Comment: what do you mean by "direction of pins"? And why do you think the information from random dudes on the interwebs is more accurate than the *manufacturers datasheet* ?

Comment: well that the first time that I faced a clockwise pin order ! that the reaseon !

Comment: Um.... maybe "5 Pin Configuration and Functions"

Comment: The page 33 pin order appears to be a bottom side view of the part - the pin order should be as on page 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 33 is a dimensional drawing. ICs with a proper datasheet will contain a "Pin Configuration" section that describes the various packages. For this particular datasheet this section is on page 3 and it explicitly states "Top View" for the VQFN package, with the pins arranged counter-clockwise.